# phaser 3 scrolling problem in mobile touch screen

Tags: scroll, touch, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I am new to phaser 3 and i don't know how to resolve this touch screen bug.
in desktop mouse scrolling working fin but in touch screen devices io wobbles and very buggy to scroll  there is 25 records list

```
    this.recordsContainer
        .setSize(580, this.maxRecordScroll - 300)
        .setInteractive().on('pointermove', (pointer) => {
            if (pointer.isDown) {
                this.recordsContainer.y += pointer.velocity.y * .2;
                if (this.recordsContainer.y >= 600) {
                    this.recordsContainer.y = 600
                }
                if (this.maxRecordScroll > 0) {
                    let minScroll = (- this.maxRecordScroll / 3) - 200
                    if (this.recordsContainer.y <= minScroll) {
                        this.recordsContainer.y = minScroll
                    }
                } else {
                    this.recordsContainer.y = 600
                }
            }
        });
```

i want scrolling same as smoth as mouse scrolling